# How can define multiple KEY in EntityFrameWorkClass C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

```
[Table("Table_UserImages")]
public class UserImage
{
     [Key, Column("UserID")]
     public Nullable<Guid> UserID { get; set; }
     [Key, Column("ImageID")]
     public Nullable<int> ImageID { get; set; }  
}
```

Both column are Primary key
but model only accept one Key  at a time,then how can i over come this? have any solution  ? please share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're describing a composite key, that is a key composed of two or more columns.

To describe this in EF, you need to also define the column ordering for the keys. Like this:

```
[Table("Table_UserImages")]
public class UserImage
{
    [Key, Column("UserID", Order=0)]
    public Guid? UserID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("ImageID", Order=1)]
    public int? ImageID { get; set; }  
}
```